# What would you call these 'native' style windows in, well, Windows?

Tags: windows, themes

I'm wanting to create my own simple application using the theme of Control Panel, Computer, etc. I don't know what you'd call this, but it simply looks like explorer with custom contents inside the same frame. If you were to open up Control Panel, Computer, Devices And Printers, or anything else that wasn't a directory, then it will have icons, buttons etc. all laid out nicely. Besides those examples, you could also check out the Troubleshooting tab under Control Panel, click on something like Internet Connections, and see what that looks like.

Essentially, I want to know how I can create windows like this:
http://prntscr.com/cdrfal

Notice how everything is nicely formatted. I hope I've explained myself well. I'm not too sure of what you would call this, but I could do the research myself. I don't know if this would be created in some sort of visual editor, or coded in something like Visual Studio, maybe with C#. If you'd know of any terms I could look up, that'd be great.

**Edit**

I've been looking at UWP and Windows Forms. Not sure if this is the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses an internal library called DirectUI for such dialogs, which isn't available to anyone else. But fundamentally there is nothing you cannot do yourself. And if things look nice and polished that's because someone put in a lot of effort to make it so. There are practically no libraries that will take an arbitrary user interface and make it magically look good.

As far as recreating such things yourself, UWP or WPF would be a fairly good start indeed, as those have more powerful layout mechanisms and are more flexible. Windows Forms of course is also an option, possibly a better one if you're not used to doing things the WPF way. Still, in any case, it takes effort to make user interfaces look good (and even more to make them work well for users).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!